# NPE while unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to write unit test for my method called `getBestSellers()`.

Here it is:

```
package bookstore.scraper.book.scrapingtypeservice;

import bookstore.scraper.enums.Bookstore;
import bookstore.scraper.book.Book;
import bookstore.scraper.fetcher.empik.EmpikFetchingBookService;
import bookstore.scraper.fetcher.merlin.MerlinFetchingBookService;
import bookstore.scraper.urlproperties.EmpikUrlProperties;
import bookstore.scraper.urlproperties.MerlinUrlProperties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static bookstore.scraper.utilities.JSoupConnector.connect;

@Service
public class BestSellersService {

    private final EmpikUrlProperties empikUrlProperties;
    private final MerlinUrlProperties merlinUrlProperties;
    private final EmpikFetchingBookService empikBookService;
    private final MerlinFetchingBookService merlinBookService;

    @Autowired
    public BestSellersService(EmpikFetchingBookService empikBookService, MerlinFetchingBookService merlinBookService, EmpikUrlProperties empikUrlProperties, MerlinUrlProperties merlinUrlProperties) {
        this.empikBookService = empikBookService;
        this.merlinBookService = merlinBookService;
        this.empikUrlProperties = empikUrlProperties;
        this.merlinUrlProperties = merlinUrlProperties;
    }

    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> getBestSellers() {
        Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> bookstoreWithBestSellers = new EnumMap<>(Bookstore.class);

        bookstoreWithBestSellers.put(Bookstore.EMPIK, empikBookService
                .get5BestSellersEmpik(connect(empikUrlProperties.getEmpik().getBestSellers())));
        bookstoreWithBestSellers.put(Bookstore.MERLIN, merlinBookService
                .get5BestSellersMerlin(connect(merlinUrlProperties.getMerlin().getBestSellers())));

        return bookstoreWithBestSellers;
    }
}
```

So, first I prepared test which looks like this:

```
package bookstore.scraper.book.scrapingtypeservice;

import bookstore.scraper.book.Book;
import bookstore.scraper.dataprovider.EmpikBookProvider;
import bookstore.scraper.dataprovider.MerlinBookProvider;
import bookstore.scraper.enums.Bookstore;
import bookstore.scraper.fetcher.empik.EmpikFetchingBookService;
import bookstore.scraper.fetcher.merlin.MerlinFetchingBookService;
import bookstore.scraper.urlproperties.EmpikUrlProperties;
import bookstore.scraper.urlproperties.MerlinUrlProperties;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BestSellersServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private EmpikFetchingBookService empikBookService;
    @Mock
    private MerlinFetchingBookService merlinBookService;
    @Mock
    private EmpikUrlProperties empikUrlProperties;
    @Mock
    private MerlinUrlProperties merlinUrlProperties;

    @InjectMocks
    private BestSellersService bestSellersService;

    @Test
    public void getBestSellers() {
        List<Book> merlinBestsellers = EmpikBookProvider.prepare5Bestsellers();
        List<Book> empikBestsellers = MerlinBookProvider.prepare5Bestsellers();

        when(empikBookService.get5BestSellersEmpik(any())).thenReturn(empikBestsellers);
        when(merlinBookService.get5BestSellersMerlin(any())).thenReturn(merlinBestsellers);
        //when(empikUrlProperties.getEmpik().getBestSellers()).thenReturn(anyString());
        //when(merlinUrlProperties.getMerlin().getBestSellers()).thenReturn(anyString());

        Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> actualMap = bestSellersService.getBestSellers();
        Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> expectedMap = null;

        assertEquals(expectedMap, actualMap);
        assertThat(actualMap).hasSize(expectedMap.size());
    }
}
```

Without setting behaviour for properties classes as I thought it is unnecessary, because I put `any()` when calling `empikBookService.get5BestSellersEmpik` (same for `merlinBookService`) but it threw NPE when calling

```
bookstoreWithBestSellers.put(Bookstore.EMPIK, empikBookService
                .get5BestSellersEmpik(connect(empikUrlProperties.getEmpik().getBestSellers())));
```

I've debugged it and I have seen that

```
empikUrlProperties.getEmpik().getBestSellers()))
```

was given me NPE.
So I set behaviour like this:

```
when(empikUrlProperties.getEmpik().getBestSellers()).thenReturn(anyString());
when(merlinUrlProperties.getMerlin().getBestSellers()).thenReturn(anyString());
```

and now it is giving me here NPE with stactrace:

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException
    at bookstore.scraper.book.scrapingtypeservice.BestSellersServiceTest.getBestSellers(BestSellersServiceTest.java:48)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
.
.
.
```

`connect` method used in tested method:

```
@UtilityClass
public class JSoupConnector {

    public static Document connect(String url) {
        try {
            return Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot connect to" + url);
        }
    }
}
```

Properties class (same for merlin)

```
package bookstore.scraper.urlproperties;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("external.library.url")
public class EmpikUrlProperties {

    private Empik empik = new Empik();

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class Empik {

        private String mostPreciseBook;
        private String bestSellers;
        private String concreteBook;
        private String romances;
        private String biographies;
        private String crime;
        private String guides;
        private String fantasy;
    }
}
```

What am I making wrong? Why it didnt work in the first place when I put `any()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems, but the main one is that you're misunderstanding how mocking, argument evaluation and `any()` work.

You're using

```
when(empikBookService.get5BestSellersEmpik(any())).thenReturn(empikBestsellers);
```

This tells the mock empikBookService than whenever its `get5BestSellersEmpik` method is called, it should return `empikBestsellers`, whetever the argument passed to the method is.

What does your actual code pass as argument when executing your test? It passes the value returned by

```
connect(empikUrlProperties.getEmpik().getBestSellers())
```

The key part is that this expression *is evaluated first*, and then its result is passed as argument to the `get5BestSellersEmpik()` method.

Just like when you do

```
System.out.println(a + b)
```

`a + b` is first evaluated. If the result is 42, then the value 42 is passed to println(), and println prints 42.

So, in order for your test not to fail, the expression

```
 connect(empikUrlProperties.getEmpik().getBestSellers())
```

must be evaluated successfully. Its result doesn't matter, since you've configure your mock to accept any argument. But that's irrelevant.

You're trying to do

```
when(empikUrlProperties.getEmpik().getBestSellers()).thenReturn(anyString());
```

That doesn't make any sense.

First, because `empikUrlProperties.getEmpik()` will return null, since `empikUrlProperties` is a mock, and mocks return null by default. And `null.getBestSellers()` will thus cause a NullPointerException.

Second, because telling a mock that it should return *any string* doesn't make sense. If you don't care about the string it should return, then choose a string by yourself, and make it return that. `anyString()` actually returns null, so you're telling it to return null.

So you need to fix that. Always think about what your code is doing instead of trying to apply a recipe.

And finally, your test also calls `connect(...)`, which is a staic method, that you haven't (and can't) mock. This method will be called too. And it tries to connect to an actual URL. So if nothing is responding during your test at that URL, that won't work either. This `connect()` method should really be part of a dependency of your service, and this dependency should be mocked.

Comment: I added `@Mock private EmpikUrlProperties.Empik empikMock;`. So when I call `getEmpik()` then it returns empikMock. The next part I should do is I think thing with `connect(..)`, but I dont understand it at all. What should I do with it? Also, should I replace `anyString` with for example `""`?

Comment: How about replacing it with a String that would be an example of a valid URL? Regarding connect(), Make it an instance method (i.e. a non-static method) of a Spring bean that you inject in the beans that need to connect, so that you can create a mock instance of that bean in your test. If you don't, then every test calling connect() will have to actually connect to a server. And you really don't want that.

Comment: You say I should change connect to non-static? Is it good way to do that? I'm asking, because I thought it is utility class, so that it is not necessary to create instance of that class.

Comment: I have put real url instead of `anyString()` as you said, but now as you said also it connects to server, which is bad. The only option is to set connect to non-static?

Comment: It's not a utility class. It downloads things from external URLs. External dependencies are really things that must be mocked when unit testing.

Comment: So to sum up, you say, I should change connect to non-static, then I should mock this JSoupConnector class? Last thing I dont understand how `when(JSoupConnector.connect()).thenReturn();` should looks like, I mena what argument should I pass into `connect()` and what should it returns.

Comment: `when(JSoupConnector.connect(theUrlThatYouChoseToMakeYourPropertiesReturn)).thenReturn(theDocumentThatYouWantToPassAsArgumentToGet5BestSellersEmpik)`. Since `get5BestSellersEmpik()`has been stubbed to return the same thing whatever the documenta is, you can choose to return any document you like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197420/discussion-between-mara122-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 1):

When you set your mock :

```
when(empikUrlProperties.getEmpik().getBestSellers()).thenReturn(anyString());
```

You have mocked `empikUrlProperties`, which is great, BUT you have not told that mock what to do when `getEmpik()` is called on it.  Consequently, that method call will return null both here in the test, and also (before you had this line) in the production code - so this is the cause of your NPE when `getBestSellers()` is called.

Consequently, set that mock up, something like :

```
@Mock
private EmpikUrlProperties empikUrlProperties;
@Mock
private EmpikUrlProperties.Empik empikMock;

when(empikUrlProperties.getEmpik()).thenReturn(empikMock);
when(empikMock.getBestSellers()).thenReturn(anyString());
```

Comment: Ah sorry - I missed the static inner class inside the properties class; updated the answer to refer to it (should work, but I can't test it at the mo).

Comment: It does not work, as it is telling me that I did invalid use of argument machers.  `When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), .....`